# Handling updates from a server route/controller in Angular

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

Hi guys i have some experience with using Angular

Basically i need to know whether i can push updates to Angular controller from the backend and how theoretically it can be done?

In the traditional REST sense i'm pulling 100 records via a get request from angular controller but how about if i wanted to call get once, then as the data is updated every second or two on the server it pushes to Angular

Answer (score 0):

I think your best chance is to implement a polling mechanism to check for updates or have a look at [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr)

Comment: I would be using java on the backend

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for websockets. Depending on your server you will need a specific module or configuration.

For nodeJS we use [socket.io](http://socket.io/)

For tomcat you can take a look at https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html